# Laravel Using two models relationships to create another model object

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Have a user and design model, user model has many preorders model and design model also has many preorders model. and preorders belongs to user and designs. (Designs also belogns to users )when creating preo orders using auth()->user()->designs()->preorders()->create displays that preorders is undefined.

[user model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjnAT.png)

[design model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uevyV.png)

[preorder model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQgJH.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpHq2.png)

[preorder controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk8mz.png)

Comment: No this is not possible. you need to write like auth()->preorders()->create([ design_id=> $desitn_id]) some thing similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a user can have many designs, it's not possible for Laravel to know which `design_id` should be associated with the preorder to be created.

```php
auth()->user()->designs()->preorders()->create([]); // Can't work because user has many designs. Which one should be used to create the preorder?
```

Instead, you should chain the preorder create method on a design:

```php
$design->preorders()->create(['user_id' => auth()->id()]); // One design and one user specified: preorder can be created.
```

or on $user:

```php
auth()->user()->preorders()->create(['design_id' => auth()->id()]); // One design and one user specified: preorder can be created.
```